# If I have 2.4 amps on 5 Volts, how many amps am I using on 220v?

Tags: led-strip

I know this sounds like a stupid question but I'm trying my best.

Anyways, I have a 2 meter RGB LED strip with 120 LEDs in total (60 leds/meter). I calculated the power consumption, which will be 2.4 Amps at 5 Volts but I can't figure out how many amps it draws at 220V.

Comment: probably zero because the strip will fry at that voltage

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$ P_{OUT} = P_{IN} \cdot Eff $$

Where P is power (W) and Eff is efficeincy.

Since \$ P = VI \$ this can be rewritten as

$$ V_{OUT}I_{OUT} = V_{IN}I_{IN} \cdot Eff $$

A decent PSU will have an efficiency of about 85% or so.

You should be able to work it out from here.